# Unity C# - How Can I detect if cmd.exe running and then make action with Unity game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, process

```
if (Process.GetProcessesByName("cmd").Length < 0)
{
      UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("CMD.exe detected!");
}
```

doesn't worked (error: InvalidOperati­onException: Process has exited, so the requested information is not available.)

Comment: You know that the `Length` of the array you get in return of the method `Process.GetProcessesByName("cmd")` will never be `< 0`. How shell it contain less than zero elements? You can check for the `Length` to be `!=` zero, to see if there are any elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way to do it with the `name` of the process:

You could simply try get the process by name `Process.GetProcessesByName(string name)`, this uses `System.Diagnostics`. So this could be a criteria to test if a process is running, in order to react to it.

```
Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("cmd");

if (pname.Length != 0)
    MessageBox.Show("cmd is running!");
else
    //...???
```

Comment: `InvalidOperati­onException: Process has exited, so the requested information is not available.`

Comment: @TomášProcházka I just tested the code and it works like a charm. So the problem isn't my provided code. Rather it is your `UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("CMD.exe detected!");`. Replace it with `MessageBox.Show("cmd is running!");` for the sake of testing to see if it detects that `cmd.exe` is running. You will see it will work.

Comment: Maybe problem is it's older unity.. but i don't think

Comment: I don't own the game, I'm modder that trying revive the game =) :/

Comment: Oh ok. So I suggest you to debug your code to get a guarantee that `UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("CMD.exe detected!");` creates the issue. Furthermore writing this message to the `Log` isnt essential, you could save the messsage you want to output somewhere else.